# Default CHARACTER_SET and COLLATION_CONNECTION changed between versions of Java MySql Connectors?

Tags: java, mysql

We're using MySql version 5.7 and all our tables \ databases use utf8_unicode_ci.
While trying to upgrade our Java connector from 5.1.38 to latest (8.0.17), we encountered the following exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Illegal mix of collations (utf8_bin,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='
```

Comparing session variables between the two connectors we noticed both `CHARACHTER_SET` and `COLLATION_CONNECTION` have changed between the versions from `utf8_bin` to `utf8mb4_general_ci`.

I know we can add to the connection string `connectionCollation=utf8_bin` but this is not super safe, and is there a way to force the MySql server to set the default collation according to the database's default collation \ character set?

Answer (score 1):

You should read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-connection.html which explains everything about client and server character sets.

As far as I know, there's no way for the client or connection character set to implicitly use the database character set. The closest thing to that is the following, which still requires the client to run a statement:

```
SET CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;
```

This implicitly sets the `character_set_connection` and `collation_connection` to that of the current default database.

I don't know why you say it's not safe to add the collation to the connection string. Isn't that what it's for?